# Modal don't close using React router and Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a component with a modal. A button trigger the modal, then if you click on the button inside the modal, you are redirect to another page (using Link) and the modal is supposed to close.
Unfortunately, if I use data-dismiss the redirection does not work anymore.
Is there another way to do it?
Here is the code and thank you for your help:

```
<div
                  className="modal fade"
                  id="exampleModal"
                  tabIndex="-1"
                  role="dialog"
                  aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                >
                  <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                      <div className="modal-header">
                        <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                          Commande OK
                        </h5>

                        <button
                          type="button"
                          className="close"
                          data-dismiss="modal"
                          aria-label="Close"
                        >
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                      <div className="modal-footer text-center">
                        <Link
                          to="/offers"
                          className="col-6 justify-content-center"
                        >
                          <button
                            type="button"
                            className="btn btn-info"
                          >
                           Back 
                          </button>
                        </Link>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: What if you have somethin like onClick={()=>{callCloseModal(event);return <Redirect to="/offers">}}

Comment: Thanks for your help Simon.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Local state in the component that has a `modalOpen` boolean property that is set to true or false depending on whether the modal is open or closed. The button on the modal should also have an `onClick` handler that sets the `modalOpen` to false once the button is clicked for redirection.

Comment: Thank you Oreoluwa I found a stateless solution but I am sure it could be done this way too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution:
I add a function to the button: `onClick={this.closeModal}`
and then just add this function before render:

```
closeModal() {
    $("#exampleModal").modal("toggle");
  }
```

Hope it helps.